# Can I have a child component in my app communicate with the main App component using context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've built my app using create react app as a one page website. I want to have dynamic titles though, and I saw in [this article](https://dev.to/jakenherman/dynamic-html-titles-in-react-with-nfl-s-helmet-2nln), that using `helmet` I can achieve that.

The thing is though, is that I'll get the values that I want set as title only in an inner dynamic page.

How can I have that page, communicate with my main app parent component? Can I use context somehow? I can't imagine how because app has no parent in which I can `App` with the context provider.
Also I a using router and can't see how I can drill down the `setState` in case I wanted to go that way.

Is the app out of communications reach?

This is my app component's code:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MetaProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <PageProvider>
          <SearchProvider>
            <ToastProvider>
              <Helmet>
                <title>{stream.title}</title>
                <meta name="description" content={stream.body} />
              </Helmet>

              <Router history={history}>
                <div className="app">
                  <SignUp />
                  <UpdateProfile />
                  <NewStream />
                  <EditedStream />
                  <Header />

                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/on/:id" exact component={Search} />
                    <Route path="/stream/:id" exact component={SingleStream} />
                    <Route path="/:id" exact component={Stranger} />
                    <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </Router>
            </ToastProvider>
          </SearchProvider>
        </PageProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </MetaProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to communicate with your App. If your Helmet component and your dynamic page are inside the same context provider, then you can store the title in the state of the context and read it inside your Helmet component.